# How to close One2many form view after clicking to view its detail?

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

**Odoo 14 Community Edition**

I have a customized form view of a customized model.

Inside the model and the view, I have a One2many field. As simple as

```
<field name="one2many_field"/>
```

The form view displays this field as a table (tree/list view), which contains records of its data in lines correctly.

When clicking one of the records, the system will popup a window showing the detail of the selected record in a form view window.

I have created a button along with its method to process something, and then I want to close this window when the process is done. How to do it?

I have tried

```
return {'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close'}
```

It displays an error, which means it does not work.

Currently, clicking the button will process everything correctly but the window is still there.

Comment: Do you need the button in the form view or is a button in the list view enough?

Comment: @CZoellner The button must be in the form view because there are already many buttons for the user to do there in the form view. However, only this one has to close the form.

Comment: Hmm, then i don't know a good answer. Did you try to return `True`? ;D

Comment: @CZoellner Tried it. Does not work. Window still opens, and no error.

Comment: i do not know of a x2many form view with buttons in odoo vanilla code. So that's probably a framework limitation.